# Qt5 access the ui from another class

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator

I created a class datafunctions in which I want to store every functions that updates a UI widget in the mainwindow. So I tried to just pass the ui as a parameter to the function. Let's say I wanted to change the text of my textEdit_data widget which is part of the mainwindow. After passing the ui as a parameter into the function formatandInsert in the class dataFunctions, I can't access any widget of the mainwindow ui. The following code gives me the error "member access into incomplete type 'Ui::MainWindow'"

```
void dataFunctions::formatandInsert(Ui::MainWindow *ui){
    ui->textEdit_data->setText("");
}
```

that's my datafunctions.h file

```
#ifndef DATAFUNCTIONS_H
#define DATAFUNCTIONS_H

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QTextEdit>

class dataFunctions
{
public:
    dataFunctions();
    void formatandInsert(Ui::MainWindow*);
};

#endif // DATAFUNCTIONS_H
```

I called the function formatandInsert in the constructor of the mainwindow like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    dataFunctions df;
    df.formatandInsert(ui);
}
```

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "I still can't access the ui". It seems that you get something else than you expected. What you expected and what you got is not described. Also whatevert that formatandInsert does is nowhere seen.

Comment: @ÖöTiib I updated it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `#include "ui_mainwindow.h"` in your `datafunctions.cpp` file. It's a header which is automatically generated by Qt Designer and it defines the `Ui::MainWindow` class.